# Using PHP files located on another server

Tags: php, mysql, server

I've been doing research for a few days now, and trying to figure out the best method (security and performance wise) of using php files on a website located on server A for a website on server B.

Sort of like a CDN?

These files are not static files per say, server B will use the php files with a server B database connection (doing updates or inserts, etc.). I will not be using a database connection from server to server.

Can someone help me with this? I'm not sure what I need to do accomplish this.

Comment: Simply put: this isn't how things are done. PHP files are code that must be present locally on the system that runs the application. You could use a network filesystem, but this is only applicable in a datacenter environment. Typically, code is *deployed* to the server when it is released.

Comment: you're looking for _Application Programming Interface_, don't you?

Comment: Server B could potentially be set up to allow you to request files, then you could exec them on Server A. You might also fetch the file from Server B, temporarily store it for processing via include or require, then immediately delete it.... Maybe...

Comment: Theres an `allow_url_include` directive for PHP, which can be exploited for remote file inclusion attack. And I'm pretty sure thats not how CDN works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something you can do easily without the proper experience to secure and the right server setup to allow the files to be transferred. If you don't need the files to read from the other server, as suggested by the CDN comment, you should just look into hosting the files directly.

If you're worried about someone inspecting where the images came from, you can use .htaccess or something similar to hide the true image path via make Apache Rewrites.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html